# Can't tap the Hot Questions widget on Android

Tags: bug, android-app, hot-questions, android-app-widgets

I have 4 copies of the *Hot Questions* widgets.

Sometimes, possibly after they reload on their own, I can only tap to open the last widget I added. If I tap on the question of any others nothing happens.

If I refresh each one then tapping works on the one I refreshed.

Comment: Actually, it looks like I can only tap on the one that was refreshed last, or if they were refreshed automatically I can't tap any of them.

Comment: Looks like [this also happens with a single widget](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246945/hot-questions-widget-doesnt-change-question-when-refreshed-appears-hung-or).